# Calculate last occurrence up until each day in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to calculate the number of times a user got to 30days without accessing their account over the past two years.

I have a dataframe which contains data in the following format (this is a sample, but there is historical data for the past two years, with all logins performed by the users):

```
+---------+-------------------+
|loginuser|               data|
+---------+-------------------+
|  2024290|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2029635|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2050969|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2078419|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2088587|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2059021|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2119433|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2139092|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2150151|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
|  2176295|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
+---------+-------------------+
```

For each day in the past 2 years, i need to validate if the user was 30 days without accessing. This part i believe i can handle just fine, but in order do so, i'd need a dataframe with the last login timestamp that user performed up until each day of the year. How do I generate this ?
This is the desired output then:

```
loginuser | calendar_day | lastlogin_timestamp
```

Having in mind that lastlogin_timestamp < calendar day

I could not think of any other way besides iterate over each day in the calendar and generate the `max(login_timestamp)`, but considering the size of my dataset, this would be insane.

Comment: It's not clear. In this dataframe, do you have historical data?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main idea is you need to group by both `loginuser` and the date that is extracted from `data`.

**sample input**

```py
# +---------+-------------------+
# |loginuser|               data|
# +---------+-------------------+
# |  2024290|2021-02-22 00:00:00|
# |  2024290|2021-02-22 01:00:00|
# |  2024290|2021-02-23 04:00:00|
# |  2024290|2021-02-23 05:00:00|
# |  2078419|2021-02-22 11:00:00|
# |  2078419|2021-02-22 12:00:00|
# |  2078419|2021-02-22 13:00:00|
# +---------+-------------------+
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .groupBy('loginuser', F.date_format('data', 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('calendar_day'))
    .agg(F.max('data').alias('lastlogin_timestamp'))
    .show()
)

# +---------+------------+-------------------+
# |loginuser|calendar_day|lastlogin_timestamp|
# +---------+------------+-------------------+
# |  2024290|  2021-02-23|2021-02-23 05:00:00|
# |  2024290|  2021-02-22|2021-02-22 01:00:00|
# |  2078419|  2021-02-22|2021-02-22 13:00:00|
# +---------+------------+-------------------+
```